# Blackberry is not defined, using Webworks

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

In my WebWorks application I have the following in my config.xml;

`<feature id="blackberry.invoke.card" />`

and in my main page I imported the following JS:
`

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/BlackBerry-JQM-Init.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/BlackBerry-JQM.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="local:///chrome/webworks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`

But whenever the code attempts to run `blackberry.invoke.card.invokeEmailComposer(...)` I get "blackberry is not defined".  What am I missing to properuly use the Blackberry libraries, specifically to send an email message?  All the examples from Github and other sites also failed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: Re-wrote since you're using WebWorks 2.0 Beta*

I see the problem. You're doing things the "old way".

Since WebWorks 2.0 is running on Cordova, a few things have changed. Really quickly, I can see that you're including the 'local:///webworks.js'. That is incorrect for v2.0.

You need to include *cordova.js* now. Take a look at the sample project that comes with WebWorks 2.0 when you create a new project.

Here's the full [Getting Started Guide](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/creating_your_first_app.html) that should get you up to speed. If you would rather use the command line, take a look at the build instructions at the end of any of the sample apps. Again, feel free to reference or use and adapt any of the sample apps as well @ https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/WebWorks-2.0

Comment: I'm actually on WW 2.  Import all libraries at the bottom instead of the <head> tag?

Comment: Will add a new answer that applies to ww2